# Where should I write my Kafka Adapter/Connector to read the data from the topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, asynchronous-postback

I am developing an application where I have several Consumers (an project which will consume a message and process it and after processing it send back to the topic where it comes from)

An Getway project which has two REST method Post method, this Post method will produce a messaage to one of the consumer and that particular consumer will process and send back to the Getway

now, I have a Get method that will consume the message which is sent back by the consumer.

but I want to remove this Get call, and I want all this done in single Post call, where I can produce a message to consumer and once the consumer processed I want to read it

how to achieve this? should I use Poll?

If so then where should I write Poll and is there a way to handle this on event basis like once message send by Getway it reads the response on some event.

In my project we used spring kafka template.

Comment: See `ReplyingKafkaTemplate`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#replying-template